# Integral $\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos(2\theta)e^{\cot\theta}}{\sin^3(2\theta)\left(e^{\cot\theta}-e^{\tan\theta}\right)}d\theta$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I was told that there is a closed form to the integral $$\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos(2\theta)e^{\cot\theta}}{\sin^3(2\theta)\left(e^{\cot\theta}-e^{\tan\theta}\right)}d\theta$$

The given answer is

> $$\frac{ \pi^2 }{48}$$

and I have verified it numerically. However, I don't know the methods used.

**My question is:** how to obtain the answer analytically?

Comment: So, why don't you share the closed form here?

Comment: As not to spoil. For those that are interested, it is $\pi^2/48$

Comment: This is a recreational problem? I mean you share it for others, or you actually need help?

Comment: Probably $\tan\theta=u$ may work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT**

First of all, notice that

\begin{align*}
\frac{\cos(2\theta)e^{\cot(\theta)}}{\sin^{3}(2\theta)(e^{\cot(\theta)}-e^{\tan(\theta)})} = \frac{\cot(2\theta)\csc^{2}(2\theta)}{1 - e^{\tan(\theta)-\cot(\theta)}} = \frac{\cot(2\theta)\csc^{2}(2\theta)}{1 - e^{-2\cot(2\theta)}}
\end{align*}

Hence, according to the substitution $w = \cot(2\theta)$, where $\mathrm{d}w = -2\csc^{2}(2\theta)\mathrm{d}\theta $, we obtain

\begin{align*}
\int\frac{\cos(2\theta)e^{\cot(\theta)}}{\sin^{3}(2\theta)(e^{\cot(\theta)}-e^{\tan(\theta)})}\mathrm{d}\theta = -\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{w}{1-e^{-2w}}\mathrm{d}w
\end{align*}

Can you proceed from here?

Comment: Yes, thank you.